# TFS Checked in items not available in view history (intermittent)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have recently experienced a strange problem in `tfs source control` . I added some code in two different parts of n-tier solution in `visual studio 2012`; code behind aspx.vb file and class library project, they appeared in pending changes, I `checked-in` and did something else in the project but later on I found the changes I made in the code are not there anymore.I checked the `view history` from `source control explorer` and those changes are not shown in view history. However If i update existing code base now and do `check-in` pending changes they are showin in view history. Can any body tell why in first place `checked-in` changes are gone from tfs or is there anything I can do to retrieve those changes. **`TFS`** server is 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that there was something wrong with the workflow you used to perform the first checkin. Checkins are atomic so you can't have some files checked in an others not.

The most common scenario would be that the scope of your checkin was incorrect.

Note: You should move ASAP to upgrade your TFS server to 2013. TFS 2008 no longer revives servicing.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't know much about scope of checkin but the same type of problem was reported by another developer in our team. one thing we were doing were excluding some files so that they should not be part of checkin and that did not cause any problem in the past so i guess it might be the cause.

Comment: The scope of the checkin is based on where you right click and select checkin.